# python, bs4, .csv -- Why is my function not repeating properly?

Tags: python, excel, csv, beautifulsoup, href

I am writing a script in python utilizing beautiful soup and trying to save multiple entries into a .csv file. As of now, I am able to successfully open up the file and automatically add the header "url" but for some reason my function is not repeating properly and not saving any of the parsed href content.

I am using pycharm for this particular project and I am receiving no errors or warnings. I have also omitted part of the code that is completely unrelated to this issue (mostly pyautogui).

```
import pyautogui, time, datetime, requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
data_list = []

def parse(site):
    if site.status_code == 200:
        content = bs(site.content, 'html.parser')
        questions = content.find_all(class_='question-summary')
        for question in questions:
            url = question.find(class_='question-hyperlink').get('href')
            new_data = {"url": url}
            data_list.append(new_data)
        with open('cyber_news.csv', 'w') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=["url"], delimiter=';')
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in data_list:
                writer.writerow(row)
    else:
        pass


# tab 1 Point(x=121, y=12)
# parse page and append to file top news articles on each web page
site = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=google+tech&source=lnms&tbm=nws'
parse(requests.get(site))
time.sleep(10)

# tab 2
# parse page and append to file top news articles on each web page
site = 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/cybersecurity/'
parse(requests.get(site))
time.sleep(10)

# tab 3
# parse page and append to file top news articles on each web page
site = 'https://www.nytimes.com/spotlight/cybersecurity'
parse(requests.get(site))
time.sleep(10)

# tab 4
# parse page and append to file top news articles on each web page
site = 'https://www.wired.com/tag/cybersecurity/'
parse(requests.get(site))
time.sleep(10)

# tab 5
# parse page and append to file top news articles on each web page
site = 'https://newcyberfrontier.podbean.com/'
parse(requests.get(site))
time.sleep(10)

# tab 6
# parse page and append to file top news articles on each web page
site = 'https://securityinfive.libsyn.com/'
parse(requests.get(site))
time.sleep(10)

# tab 7
# parse page and append to file top news articles on each web page
site = 'https://www.vice.com/en/topic/cybersecurity'
parse(requests.get(site))
time.sleep(2)

exit()
```

I am still learning python and I will take all criticism to improve.

Comment: Well, your looking for a class `question-summary` on all the webpages. every webpage has different HTML markup. why would google.com and washingtonpost have the same markup?

Comment: I didn't consider that, I had originally planned to create a specific script for each individual website but decided to try and lump them all in a function to condense lines. Thank you!

Comment: For the specific sites, is the output correct? if not - what site?

Comment: Currently there is no output, it just creates the .csv file and writes "url" in A1. I've tried changing " with open('cyber_news.csv', 'w') as file:" to  with open('cyber_news.csv', 'a') as file: -- no change.

Comment: Is your code literally wrapped by a triple-quote, or is that just your post here on SO?  That marks the code as a comment block and will be ignored when the code is compiled and run. Since you say that your script creates the CSV file, I'm guessing it's not commented out "in real life".

Comment: @DaveL17 yeah sorry, this was my first post on SO, those quotes are not in the real script

Comment: @fischdix No worries my friend. Just ruling out possibilities when there's no error messages to go on.